# Orchard Context Null in Authorizer Class

Tags: c#, orchardcms

On line 72 of the `Authorizer` class I'm getting a null reference exception:

```
if (_authorizationService.TryCheckAccess(permission, _workContextAccessor.GetContext().CurrentUser, content))
```

The problem is with `GetContext()` returning `null` so, obviously, referencing `CurrentUser` will cause me problems.

Originally, it's a migration creating taxonomy terms that's resulting in this call to the Authorizer. In fact, the full stack trace can be found below this post.

I've tried everything in terms of refactoring the migration, but it is code that has been proven 3 times elsewhere in the code (one of which is in a migration - so I feel assured that the 'context' in which I'm doing this is fine).

**Migration code:**

```
        var taxonomy = _contentManager.New<TaxonomyPart>("Taxonomy");
        taxonomy.Name = "Categories";
        _contentManager.Create(taxonomy, VersionOptions.Published);

        var parentTerm = _taxonomyService.NewTerm(taxonomy);
        parentTerm.Name = "Products";
        parentTerm.Container = taxonomy.ContentItem;
        _contentManager.Create(parentTerm, VersionOptions.Published);
        string[] childTermNames = { "Disks", "Mice", "Keyboards" };

        foreach (var termName in childTermNames)
        {
            var term = _taxonomyService.NewTerm(taxonomy);
            term.Name = termName;
            term.Container = parentTerm.ContentItem;
            _contentManager.Create(term, VersionOptions.Published);
        }
```

**Explanation:**

This code creates a 'Categories' taxonomy. Inside this taxonomy is a `Products` term, this is to be the parent term of all the subsequent child terms and so is assigned as the container.

The result of which is that the taxonomy is created, but the terms aren't hierarchical (they all exist on one level).

**Stack Trace:**

```
2015-02-13 15:47:32,955 [23] Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager - (null) - NullReferenceException thrown from IContentHandler by Orchard.Autoroute.Handlers.AutoroutePartHandler
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Orchard.Security.Authorizer.Authorize(Permission permission, IContent content, LocalizedString message) in \Site\src\Orchard\Security\Authorizer.cs:line 72
   at Orchard.Security.Authorizer.Authorize(Permission permission) in \Site\src\Orchard\Security\Authorizer.cs:line 60
   at Orchard.Autoroute.Handlers.AutoroutePartHandler.ProcessAlias(AutoroutePart part)
   at Orchard.Autoroute.Handlers.AutoroutePartHandler.PublishAlias(AutoroutePart part)
   at Orchard.Autoroute.Handlers.AutoroutePartHandler.<.ctor>b__2(PublishContentContext ctx, AutoroutePart part)
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.ContentHandler.InlineStorageFilter`1.Published(PublishContentContext context, TPart instance) in Site\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Handlers\ContentHandler.cs:line 164
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.StorageFilterBase`1.Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.IContentStorageFilter.Published(PublishContentContext context) in Site\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Handlers\StorageFilterBase.cs:line 87
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.ContentHandler.Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.IContentHandler.Published(PublishContentContext context) in Site\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Handlers\ContentHandler.cs:line 288
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.<>c__DisplayClass5e.<Create>b__5b(IContentHandler handler) in \Site\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 534
   at Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) in Site\src\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line 17
```

Comment: That doesn't look like code that belongs in a migration: migrations are for altering the DB schema and changing content definitions. Did you try to do the work from a recipe instead?

Comment: I did consider this was possibly the wrong part of the solution to populate tables from, but I was simply following the Orchard docs, which do exactly that: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations#PopulatingtheStateTable Should I expect Orchard to throw null reference exceptions when creating data is done in the migration? I've done this many times before and it has been fine. *This* content-creating code, itself, was fine - up until the point I attempted to assign parent items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue as you, I found the solution looking at the TermAdminController.

Here is a sample:

```
   var parentTerm = _taxonomyService.NewTerm(categoriesTaxonomy);
   parentTerm.Container = categoriesTaxonomy.ContentItem;

   // Create content item before updating so attached fields save correctly
   _orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(parentTerm, VersionOptions.Draft);
   parentTerm.Name = "main category";
   parentTerm.Selectable = true;

   _taxonomyService.ProcessPath(parentTerm);
   _orchardServices.ContentManager.Publish(parentTerm.ContentItem);

   var subTerm = _taxonomyService.NewTerm(categoriesTaxonomy);

   //here you set the parent term
   subTerm.Container = parentTerm == null ? categoriesTaxonomy.ContentItem : parentTerm.ContentItem;

   // Create content item before updating so attached fields save correctly
   _orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(subTerm, VersionOptions.Draft);
   subTerm.Name = "sub category";
   subTerm.Selectable = true;

   _taxonomyService.ProcessPath(subTerm);
   _orchardServices.ContentManager.Publish(subTerm.ContentItem);
```

Hope it helps!